# Help on Wifi Thermostat Wiring Guide

Tags: thermostat, air-conditioning, thermostat-c-wire, wifi

I do have the WiFi thermostat (picture attached) that I m trying to attached with my current central airconditioning unit but no success after trying multiple wiring. I does have three wires coming to the current thermostat (picture attached below)

Can someone help me if this exisiting thermostat can work or any other WiFi thermostat can work with the exisiting Air-condition

Same WiFi thermostat was working perfectly fine earlier in a different apartment.

WiFi Thermostat
[image]
[image]
[image]

Installed Air Condition
[image]

Air Condition Circuit
[image]

Current Thermostat
[image]

Comment: Can you suggest the WiFi controller for this specific model

Answer (score 5):

### You'll need a WiFi controller specific to your make and model of air conditioner

Your air conditioner is of a type called a "mini-split", which generally uses a proprietary protocol between the indoor controller and the main control board in the outdoor unit, instead of relying on contact closure signalling from the thermostat the way North American split systems traditionally have.  As a result, you can't just buy any old thermostat and hang it off your air conditioner -- instead, you need a controller made to work specifically with your particular make and model of air conditioner.

Comment: Can you suggest the WiFi controller for this specific model

Comment: @AbdulRafy -- you're best off poking Fujitsu directly